# Converting number to string in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to express the result of "funct" as a string but nothing I've tried is working.

```
def funct(y):   
    rad = [2+y]
    return rad
z = 1;
a = funct(z);
print a
print str(a)
b = str(a);
print b
c = repr(a);
print c
```

Here's my output:

```
[3]
[3]
[3]
[3]
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Edit: I meant that I'm trying to print it as a string without the brackets. Forgot to include that.

Comment: What result do you want? `3`? `["3"]`?

Comment: Your first `print` calls `str` implicitly, and the second and third `print`s are doing exactly the same. The fourth `print` uses `repr`, which happens to be equivalent to `str` for a list with integers.

If you only want `funct` to return `2+4`, use `rad = (2+y)` or just `rad = 2+y`, since `[2+y]` creates a list with one element.

Comment: `str(a)` is a string, what's the problem?

Comment: just access it with slice notation: ie. `a[0]` yields `"3"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a list to a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616828/converting-a-list-to-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want `rad` to be a list.

Try using `()` instead of `[]`:

```
rad = (2+y)
```

Your function would work like so:

```
def funct(y):   
    rad = (2 + y)
    return rad
z = 1;
a = funct(z);
print a 
#=> "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your question, you don't want to change `funct` itself and you don't want to convert the output of `funct` into a string. If you want to change *a number* into *a string* you need to change the values inside the list output by `funct`. The problem is that you're turning the repr of the list itself into a string, but not casting the value in the list:

```
>>> repr([5])
'[5]'
>>> repr(["5"])
"['5']"
```

You actually want to cast the value in the list:

```
>>> repr(list(map(str, [5]))) # say `funct(3)` for example
"['5']"
>>> repr(list(str(i) for i in [5]))
"['5']"
```

Now, if you really just want to turn the output of `funct` into a string, you're already doing that. Python's just not printing quotes around the *string representation of a list* because it's printing it.

```
>>> repr([5]); print([5])
'[5]'
[5]
```